# What is this thing they talk about Sarah?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-neon-demon

In the movie Neon Demon, there is a scene where the girls audition. Sarah's turn approaches and the lady who's organizing the audition says "Robert, you remember Sarah?". After that they whisper something, and Robert says "oh.". After that he doesn't even look at her auditioning for the part.

What is it that they exchange about Sarah here?